# How does fluent nhibernate know which tables to access?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I read the tutorial
http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping#Getting_started

but I couldn't undersatnd how the tables are accessed?

I don't give any naming convenstion, so how is the mapping done?

In `hbm.xml`, there is a declaration:

```
<class name="Cat" table="Cat">
```

but in fluent there is not.

Comment: What tutorial? You forgot to link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using ClassMap, use the Table declaration:

```
  public class ExampleMap : ClassMap<Example>
  {
    public ExampleMap()
    {
        Table("MyExampleTable");
        Id(a => a.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    }
  }
```

If you're using AutoMapping, see the documentation at http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping for how to set up Overrides

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely specify table name in your mapper. But if you are interested to know how it automatically maps, then you need to know the conventions how Fluent NHibernate do.

Read [this](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Conventions) chapter on Conventions.

Answer (score 0):

With fluent you will map your tables in a class. For example:

```
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;

namespace Models.Mapping
{
    public class CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer>
    {
        public CustomerMap()
        {
            Table("Customer");
            Id(customer => customer.Id);
            Map(customer => customer.Name).Column("client_name").Not.Nullable();
            Map(ssc => customer.ssc).Column("social_security_numer");

            References(customer => customer.User);
        }
    }
}
```

This just show how to map your table. It's very simple as you can see. You won't use hbm.xml to map anymore and remember to register your mappings like:

```
ISessionFactory SessionFactory = Fluently.Configure(configuration).Mappings(m =>
                          {
                              m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<CustomerMap>();
                          }).BuildSessionFactory();
```

Just a simple example, you can find more in the fluent reference.

Comment: i'm working with a friend on the same solution. He is willing to use hbm.xml, so he configured SessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory(); can I add my mapping config to this?